# Java Transactional method exclud rollback for certain inner method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

Hi have the following code snippet what im trying to do is having a main transactional method
that rollback all the inserts but i want to avoid rollback for some escenario in particular,
i mean do all the whole rollback all other nested method excluding a few o them

`public class myClass {

```
private DepositCancelledRepository depositRepo;

private DepositCancelledRepository depositCancelledRepo;

@DistributedLock(name = "mylocal", value = "#depositId")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, noRollbackFor = NoRollbackException.class)
public void outerMethod() {
        saveDeposit()
        saveDepositCancelled(depositCancelled);
        otherMethhods that will throw ex for rollback

}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveDeposit(DepositCancelled depositCancelled) {
        depositCancelledRepo.save(depositCancelled);

}

public void saveDepositCancelled(DepositCancelled depositCancelled) {

        depositRepo.save(depositCancelled);
}
```

}`

in this example i want to avoid rollback saveDepositCancelled even if the outerMethod throws exception , tried with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW but not worked if outer method fails whith exception saveDeposit should rollback and saveDepositCancelled shoudld not rollback

Answer (score 0):

Transactions in Spring work thanks to proxies.

So when your method saveDeposit or saveDepositCancelled are called Spring won't see the annotations because you execute them already within your proxy instance.

If you want to achieve that you need to separate your code in several services or have one calling the different methods from outside.